# Java how to use BufferedReader to read txt files with this format

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a couple of txt files with this format and I need to read them and gather the information.

file1.txt:
[image]
file2.txt:
[image]

I only want to read the "file" section, which it can save "file" to a string, and all its sub-content to another string.

(for example, in file1.txt:)

```
String file = "file";
```

I want to write a for loop to read all the sub-content and save to another String to be like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSubcontentLines; i++){
    sub = sub + br.readLine() + ", ";
}
```

The difficulties for me is different txt files have different lines of sub-content, and I have no idea how to read these lines so that the method can work in both cases.

Current Code I tried:

```
public void readFile(String fileLocation) throws IOException {
    fileMap = new HashMap<>();
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileLocation);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line;
    String file;
    // Assign a temp value to save the sub-content
    String temp = "";
    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains("file")){
            file = "file";
            // Skip the next line
            br.readLine();
            // save all the sub-contents
            do {
                temp = temp + br.readLine() + ", ";
            } while(br.readLine().contains("****"));
        }
    }
    fileMap.put(file, temp);
    System.out.println(fileMap);
}
```

It doesn't get what I wanted. Any suggestions or ideas? Tkx in advanced.

Comment: Presumably, you are writing a method. What are the inputs to the method? (I am guessing the name of the file, but the other part might be the "section" name of the file. In your example, this might be "file", but it could also have been "apple" if you wanted to read the "apple" section). What would be the desired output? What can be assumed about the file format?

Comment: Best for you to first try to write this code yourself, experiment with your code and try to come with a working program. If that fails, then you can ask a much more specific question, showing us this code attempt (a complete small compilable and runnable program). Without this attempt, your question devolves into a request for code, which is not allowed. I'm sure that given your knowledge and skills you will either solve this or get quite close to a solution through a decent attempt (and a lot of writing down logic of code flow on paper).

Comment: You're reading in lines in too many disparate places, and are not able to handle things correctly. Instead you need to create a state machine -- a single while loop that does the line reading (not a bunch of locations for reading the line, and then this feeds the line into the state machine which will handle the line in various ways depending on its *state*.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I uploaded my codes, it does not work though.

Comment: States can include: START (searching for start text cue), READ (start text found, and now reading in text -- all the while looking for end text cue), and DONE (end text cue found), and can be encapsulated by an enum.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create and use a state machine, an object that holds state (an enum or booleans can work for this), that is given each line of text and then handles each line depending on its state. A schematic of code flow could look like this:

[image]

Other states can include input or file end.
A key point being that the line should be read at one point only, within the while loop, and then the loop passes the text on to the other part of the code that handles it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I will try to work on this way and see if I can solve it.